OpenSSHサーバーのポート番号22がクライアントからアクセスできない
[環境]
サーバー    : mx-Linux21.3 (Sambaで共有フォルダを開放済み)
$ hostname    → main-pc
$ hostname -I → 192.169.1.13
クライアント: Windows10
[OpenSSHのバージョン]
サーバー    : OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3, OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
クライアント: OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
[希望]
LinuxサーバーにWindowsクライアントで「パスワード認証」でLAN環境でファイル転送をしたい
あくまでクローズな環境での利用です
[問題点]
１，WindowsクライアントからlinuxサーバーのSSHポート22番にアクアセスできない
２，サーバー側のTerminalで、コマンド：$ sshd -T で下記エラーがでる
error: sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.

３，下記表記の「h. ポート番号を確認」で「#GatewayPorts no」が良いのか悪いのか判断つきません
[質問]
サーバー側が悪いのか、クライアント側の設定が必要なのか解りません
下記に私が行ったことを記述しますので、訂正箇所や追加しないといけないことが
有りましたら、ご指摘ください。宜しくお願い致します
#----- ここから私が行った行動です -----
<①サーバー側で行ったこと>
a.
OpenSSHのインストール            $ sudo apt install openssh-server
b.
/etc/ssh/sshd_configで設定を追加した項目
 Port 22
 PubkeyAuthentication no
 PermitRootLogin no
 PermitEmptyPasswords no
 PasswordAuthentication yes
 
 ※ 元々/etc/ssh/sshd_configで'#(コメントアウト)'を外してあった項目
     
 Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
 UsePAM yes
 X11Forwarding yes
 PrintMotd no
 AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
 Subsystem  sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
 

c.
# SSHサーバーを再起動              $ sudo service ssh restart
# sshサービスを停止する         $ sudo service ssh stop
# 自動起動を有効にする           $ sudo systemctl enable ssh
d.
ポート番号確認:22                $ nc -vz 192.168.1.13 22
 main-pc [192.168.1.13] 22 (ssh) open
 

e.
OpenSSHが稼働しているか確認 $ sudo service ssh status
 sshd is running.
 

f.
ポートが開いているかを確認     $ sudo netstat -apn | grep :22
 tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:22    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  6476/sshd: /usr/sbi 
 tcp6   0   0 :::22         :::*        LISTEN  6476/sshd: /usr/sbi
 

g.
22ポートを使っているプロセスを確認    $ sudo lsof -i :22
 COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
 sshd    6476 root    3u  IPv4  42968      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
 sshd    6476 root    4u  IPv6  42970      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
 

h.
ポート番号を確認              $ grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 #Port 22
 #GatewayPorts no
 Port 22
 

i.
ファイアウォールのルールも確認
$ sudo iptables-save  # IPv4 ルールを表示
$ sudo ip6tables-save # IPv6 ルールを表示
 ※ 「dport 22」を検索ましたが、該当語句はヒットしませんでした
 

<②WindowsクライアントはOpenSSHのバージョン確認をし
サーバー側にPowershellを起動してコマンドを打ちました>
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　192.168．1.13 -Port 22
または
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　main-pc -Port 22
警告: TCP connect to (192.168.1.13 : 22) failed
ComputerName   : 192.168．1.13
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False
もしくは下記になります
ComputerName           : main-pc
RemoteAddress          : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:75e4:1d46:e7ab:ec31
RemotePort             : 22
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:46b9:fabc:8dce:1f3c
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 6 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False    ← ここがTrueでないとけない
Rookie様
確認したいのですが
＞Linux側のユーザーアカウントにパスワードは設定されていますか？
上記の意味はLinuxPCを起動した時に入力するパスワードのことですか？
これならrootもuserもパスワードは設定してます。
そうではなくOpenSSHに固有のパスワード設定なら「設定してません」
※ 設定方法を知りません
＞rootユーザーへのアクセスを許可する一連のオプションを有効にしてみてください
/etc/ssh/sshd_configで設定を変更した項目
PermitRootLogin no　⇒　PermitRootLogin yes
※ 他にどのような項目があるのでしょうか？
※ ネットで下記項目を知りましたが試していません
without-password
(パスワードを使用したrootユーザのログインを拒否)
forced-commands-only
(rootユーザの直接ログインを拒否するが、root権限を使うコマンドのアクセスは許可)
※ LinuxPCを再起動し、更に、SSHサーバーも再起動しました
※ $ sshd -T     ⇒   sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting
【上記を実行した後、Windows側でpingテスト】
理由が解らないのですが、①と②ではエラーの詳細がことなります
①Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　192.168．1.13 -Port 22
②Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　main-pc -Port 22
①のエラー
警告: Name resolution of 192.168．1.13 failed
ComputerName   : 192.168．1.13
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False
②のエラー（なぜかPingはTrueです）
警告: TCP connect to (240d:1a:baf:ae00:75e4:1d46:e7ab:ec31 : 22) failed
警告: TCP connect to (192.168.1.13 : 22) failed
ComputerName           : main-pc
RemoteAddress          : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:75e4:1d46:e7ab:ec31
RemotePort             : 22
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:46b9:fabc:8dce:1f3c
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 3 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
（２）Rookie様、cubic様へ、質問します
追伸、その後、試したこと
$ ssh localhost ⇒   私のマシンで実行したら下記エラーがでました
error:
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:#----- 暗号キーが表示されてました----
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
no　(で回避しました)
訳：
ホスト 'localhost (::1)' の信頼性を確立できません。
ECDSA キーのフィンガープリントは SHA256:#----- 暗号キーが表示されてました---- です。
接続を続行しますか (はい/いいえ/[フィンガープリント])?
ファイアウォール(ufw)を使ったポート(22)の開放方法
1.ファイアウォール(ufw)が稼働中か調べる ⇒   $ sudo ufw status verbose
2.ファイアウォール22番を開放する          ⇒   $ sudo ufw allow 22
3.設定変更したらufwをリロードする     ⇒   $ sudo ufw reload
4.ufwの既存のルールを確認する           ⇒   $ sudo ufw status verbose
[多分開放されてると思います]
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
445/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
445/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6) 

【Windowsクライアントから】
#----- OKみたいです -----
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　main-pc -Port 22

ComputerName     : main-pc
RemoteAddress    : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:75e4:1d46:e7ab:ec31
RemotePort       : 22
InterfaceAlias   : イーサネット
SourceAddress    : 240d:1a:baf:ae00:12b5:22ef:eb55:f153
TcpTestSucceeded : True 

#----- NGみたいです -----
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName　192.168．1.13 -Port 22

警告: Name resolution of 192.168．1.13 failed

ComputerName   : 192.168．1.13
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False

#----- うまく行かないです -----
PS C:\Users\user> ssh -l main-pc 192.168.1.13

main-pc@192.168.1.13's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
main-pc@192.168.1.13's password:

パスワード入力を求められたが、ログインパスワードでは入れません
Permission denied (publickey,password).
権限が拒否されました (公開鍵、パスワード)。

【Linuxサーバー側でもやってみました】
ssh -l main-pc 192.168.1.13

The authenticity of host '192.168.1.13 (192.168.1.13)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:#----- 暗号キーが表示されてました-----
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.13' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

main-pc@192.168.1.13's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
main-pc@192.168.1.13's password: 

相変わらす下記のエラーはでます
$ sshd -T
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
(3)コメント頂いた皆様へ、大変ご親切な対応、本当にありがとうございます
解決されみたいです(初めての経験なので確証が持てませんが。。。)
main-pcはlinuxサーバーのpc名でユーザー名ではありませんでした
お騒がせいたしました。
皆様のご指示通り、下記コマンドを実行しました。
[質問１] ログインできたのでアクセス出来たといえるのでしょうか？
①ssh -l root 192.168.1.13　または　ssh root@192.168.1.13　コマンド実行
PS C:\Users\xxxx> ssh -l root 192.168.1.13
root@192.168.1.13's password:
Linux dell-mee 5.10.0-33-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.226-1 (2024-10-03) x86_64
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
root@main-pc:~#
②ssh -l user 192.168.1.13　または　ssh user@192.168.1.13　コマンド実行
PS C:\Users\xxxx> ssh yyyy@192.168.1.13
yyyy@192.168.1.13's password:
Linux dell-mee 5.10.0-33-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.226-1 (2024-10-03) x86_64
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have no mail.
yyyy@main-pc:~
$
[質問２] 隠しファイルの/home/yyyy/.ssh/known_hostsは必要なのでしょうか？
削除しても大丈夫でしょうか？ 間違えた名前[main-pc]で入力した時に作成されたファイルです
ssh -l main-pc 192.168.1.13
'''
[質問３] セキュリティ上、rootによるログインをさけるため
/etc/ssh/sshd_configの内容を下記に変更しましたが、問題ないでしょうか？
#  今回の処理はパスワード認証に特化したもの
Port 22
PubkeyAuthentication yes                # パスワード認証を許可
PermitRootLogin no                      # rootユーザのログインを禁止（必須）
PermitEmptyPasswords no                 # 空パスワードを無効（必須）
PasswordAuthentication yes              # パスワード認証有効

[質問４] 　ssh yyyy@192.168.1.13でログイン後、'$ ls' でディレクトリ内のファイルを表示させると日本語が文字化けてます
どのうに文字化けを解決するのでしょうか？
Rookie様をはじめ多く方にアドバイスを頂き、問題の多くが解決できました。
本当にありがとうございました。今後も分からないことをお聞きする機会がると思います
その節はまた、お力を貸していただけますよう宜しくお願い致します
BOO-SAMURAI

サーバ上で直接 ssh localhost で接続できるか試してみましょう。また、”クライアントからアクセスできない" だけでなく、エラーメッセージ等も確認してみてください。ssh -vv サーバ のようにオプションを付けると詳細なメッセージが表示されるはずです。また、サーバ上でファイアウォールがもし動いているなら、一時的に止めた状態で試してみましょう。

コメントありがとうございます。試しましたらエラーがでました。上記質問投稿欄に掲載させて頂きました。ご精査頂ければ幸いです

例えば USER のユーザー名(ユーザーアカウント)がサーバーにあるのなら
ssh USER@192.168.1.13 (もしくは ssh -l USER 192.168.1.13) でログインしてみてください。(main-pcはホスト名のはず)

cubic様、毎回ご親切にアドバイス、本当にありがとうございます。うまく行ったようです。上記質問投稿欄に詳細及び質問を掲載しました。お時間のある時にご精査いただけると幸いです

oriri様、ご親切にアドバイス、本当にありがとうございます。うまく行ったようです。上記質問投稿欄に詳細及び質問を掲載しました。お時間のある時にご精査いただけると幸いです

当サイトでは基本的に 一問一答形式 になるような質問の仕方を推奨しているので、後だしで色々な疑問を追記していくのはあまり良い質問ではありません。chroot に関する記述以降は、別の質問で仕切り直すことを検討してください。

そうでしか。すみません。以後、気をつけます。「【４】chrootの設定において（最後の）質問があります」の件も、新しく仕切り直します

Linux側のユーザーアカウントにパスワードは設定されていますか？
またPrtmissionRootLoginなど、rootユーザーへのアクセスを許可する一連のオプションを有効にしてみてください

上記の意味はLinuxPCを起動した時に入力するパスワードのことですか？

はい
SSHでのログイン時には必ずパスワードが設定されたユーザーが必要です
Linuxでのログイン時にパスワードが求められる場合は問題ありません

/etc/ssh/sshd_configで設定を変更した項目
PermitRootLogin no　⇒　PermitRootLogin yes
※ 他にどのような項目があるのでしょうか？
※ ネットで下記項目を知りましたが試していません

以下の項目を確認してください
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes

また、仮に以下のような属性が付随する場合
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password

設定値をコメントアウトし、以下のように編集しましょう
PermitRootLogin yes #prohibit-password


ssh -l main-pc 192.168.1.13

このmain-pcはWindows側のユーザーアカウントですか？
もしLinux側のユーザー名でなければ以下に置き換えましょう
ssh -l root 192.168.1.13
または
ssh root@192.168.1.13


セキュリティ上、rootによるログインをさけるため
/etc/ssh/sshd_configの内容を下記に変更しましたが、問題ないでしょうか？

rootユーザー以外でアクセスに成功している場合は問題ありません
rootユーザーへのアクセスはサーバーの稼働状態を把握する手段に有用です
例えばユーザー管理下のディレクトリへファイルを転送できない場合、rootを経由することで解決を図ることができます
(ssh経由のgitリポジトリへのプッシュ等)
[質問４] 　ssh yyyy@192.168.1.13でログイン後、'$ ls' でディレクトリ内のファイルを表示させると日本語が文字化けてます
chcp 932でUTF-8に設定するなど、文字コードを変更してみてください
質問が多いので、時間が空き次第の回答となりますが、まず一点

home/yyyy/.ssh/known_hostsは必要なのでしょうか？

ログイン情報を保持するファイルなので削除してはいけません
サーバー情報が何らかの事情で変更された場合、クライアント側で以下のコマンドを実行し、ログインエラーを解消する際に必要となります
ssh-keygen -R [ipv4]:port


Rookie様へコメント（質問）をしたいのですが、コメントが改行できないので（末尾にスペース２個でできるとヘルプにありますが、、、）質問投稿欄、末尾に追加しておきます

（２）Rookie様へ、お忙しい中、コメント頂きありがとうございます。  ご明示頂いた項目を'etc/ssh/sshd_config'で変更し再起動しましたが、結果は変わらずでした  再度、質問を質問投稿欄、末尾に追加しておきますのでお時間が有るときに精査して頂ければ幸いです

rootでのログインはセキュリティ上問題があるのでやめたほうがよいでしょう。それに PermitRootLogin no 指定があるので許可されてません。

oriri様、ご親切にアドバイス、本当にありがとうございます。ご指摘ありがとうございます。コメントを見落としてしまい。行き違いになりすみません。上記アドバス通りに致します。皆様のおかげで本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Roolie様、お忙しい中、コメント頂きありがとうございます。known_hostsの件は了解致しました。「【４】chrootの設定において（最後の）質問があります」については、新規問い合わせに掲載するこに致しました。本当にご指導・ご回答、ありがとうございました
